# Rebar ./bin/sp restart report {'cannot load',asn1rt_nif,get_files} and can not start

Tags: linux, erlang, rebar

### Environment

```
Mac OS X 10.10.5
Erlang/OTP: 17.5
rebar 2.6.0 17 20150818_094957 git 2.6.0-16-g3239e74-dirty
```

It is an example of application from the book Programming Erlang. I have git push to [github](https://github.com/mingchaoyan/sellaprime)

Steps to reproduce the error

### build

`$ git clone https://github.com/mingchaoyan/sellaprime.git
...
$ cd sellaprime
$ rebar prepare-deps
...
$ rebar compile
...`

### release

`$ mkdir rel
$ cd rel
$ rebar create-node nodeid=sp
...`

edit reltool.config as follow

````
```
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
%% ex: ft=erlang
{sys, [
       {lib_dirs, []},
       {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
       {app_file, strip},
       {rel, "sp", "1.0.0",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib,
         sasl,
         goldrush,
         lager,
         sp
        ]},
       {rel, "start_clean", "",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib
        ]},
       {boot_rel, "sp"},
       {profile, embedded},
       {incl_cond, derived},
       {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
       {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/(?!start_clean.boot)",
                           "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                           "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
       {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
       {app, goldrush, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, "../deps/goldrush"}]},
       {app, lager, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, "../deps/lager"}]},
       {app, sp, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]}
      ]}.

{target_dir, "sp"}.

{overlay, [
           {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
           {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
           {copy, "files/nodetool", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/nodetool"},
           {copy, "sp/bin/start_clean.boot",
                  "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/start_clean.boot"},
           {copy, "files/sp", "bin/sp"},
           {copy, "files/sp.cmd", "bin/sp.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
          ]}.
```
````

then

`$ rebar generate
...`

### start

`$ cd sp
$ ./bin/sp start
$ ./bin/sp getpid
...
$ ./bin/sp attach`

start an another erlang shell

```
erl -name 'other@127.0.0.1' -noinput -noshell -eval "rpc:call('sp@127.0.0.1', init, restart, [])" -setcookie sp
```

then the first erlang shell will report

```
sp@127.0.0.1)1> {"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',asn1rt_nif,get_files}}
```

How this happened?

And why asn1rt will be released, actually I didn't config it in reltool.config

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer in [this old rebar issue](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/issues/45): you need to prevent the boot script from loading the `crypto` module. To do this, edit the `sp/bin/sp` script and remove `-mode embedded` from the `CMD` variable setting, changing this:

```
CMD="$BINDIR/erlexec $SLIM_ARGS -boot $RUNNER_BASE_DIR/releases/$APP_VSN/$BOOTFILE -mode embedded -config $CONFIG_PATH -args_file $VMARGS_PATH"
```

to this:

```
CMD="$BINDIR/erlexec $SLIM_ARGS -boot $RUNNER_BASE_DIR/releases/$APP_VSN/$BOOTFILE -config $CONFIG_PATH -args_file $VMARGS_PATH"
```